# The LAUNCHER seldom works

Tags: 12.04, launcher

At first upgrade to 12.04 the launcher would not pop out.  After the first update it began to work, but it no longer does.  I have altered the settings in APPEARANCE, and even pressing the super key does not work.  I can get HUD by tapping, Shortcuts by holding, but not launcher by pressing.  I have installed DOCKY as a work-around.

BTW 12.04 has been awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Your upgrade has not been successful. As you now have a faulty installation, take this opportunity of backing up absolutely everything you might later want.  Then have a go at some or all of the following:

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^

don't forget the caret in the above

sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get -f install

Oh and unity --reset has been known to be good.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it is difficult to get it to pop out, but if you move the pointer hard and fast to the left it does then work, for me anyway.